# Is it possible to trigger a lambda init in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Aws lambdas have 3 steps in their lifecycle:

- init
- invoke
- shutdown

Is there a way to trigger automatically a lambda init without deploying any code?

Update:

I have some actions that are launched during the init: saving the content of a file in a variable. Then during the invoke actions, the content is not downloaded anymore. But I need to launch the action of downloading from time to time. Then, I was wondering if there's a way to trigger the init action.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have some actions that are launched during the init: saving the content of a file in a variable. Then during the invoke actions, the content is not downloaded anymore. But I need to launch the action of downloading from time to time. Then, I was wondering if there's a way to trigger the init action.

Comment: Which language are you using? Can you show us some sample code to try and reproduce your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call your `init()` function again?

Take the following Go Lambda for example:

```golang
// handleRequest does process every request to the Lambda.
func handleRequest(ctx context.Context) error {
    init() // <-- call it whenever you want in your handler again
}

// init does store some data from a file in a variable.
func init() {}

func main() {
    init() // <-- called on the first start of the Lambda
    lambda.Start(handleRequest)
}
```

The `init` function is called in the `main()` method, which is executed when the Lambda is started for first time (cold start or init). But if you move your "business logic" for the initialisation into a separate function, you can call it whenever you want in your handler function.

Note: I don't think at all that this is a great idea. It is definitely a design "smell" if you need/want to do something like this. So you should rather rethink what you are doing than building workarounds like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can manually trigger those events as I know however, you can perform some action for those events.

check AWS Extention API if you are interested.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should take a look at lambda layers. This allows you to place some files in advance, so that your invocations can access it at runtime (without having to download it). You can then easily update your layer whenever you need.

[See documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this in NodeJs Lambdas. I’m not aware of any previous solutions for JS Lambdas. Normally, the lambda container is paused before async operations complete in the init phase.

The key is to leverage an AWS Lambda custom Extension. Then if you enable provisioned concurrency, the Lambdas execute the init phase before a request. You have to determine how many provisioned concurrency instances to keep online because concurrent requests can trigger on-demand instances. Or you can enable auto-scaling with provisioned concurrency to try to scale out ahead of the load.

This article explains the details and includes a link to the GitHub sample repo.

https://barker.tech/aws-lambda-nodejs-async-init-88b5c24af567?source=friends_link&sk=79dbb80045ad97c62f58fa4b74ade68b

https://github.com/chuckbarkertech/nodejs-example-async-init-extension

You still have to deploy code. But you can trigger the init before requests hit the lambda by combining provisioned concurrency with AWS Lambda Extensions like the example info above.